# How to find records with a similar string (regex)?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have some problems in my database. I have some `http://` and some `https://` links. I need to switch all `http://` to `https://`, but there's a small problem, some links are duplicates (have both versions) so if I attempt to change, I will get duplicate error.

How can I find those? I have thought in using regex `[.]com\/[a-zA-Z]*` which will trim for example `http://www.somewebsite.com/abc.gif` to `.com/abc` (implying all are .com of course, if not it won't work).

Can someone help me build an SQL command for that? I tried using mariadb  `REGEXPR_SUBSTR` but I didnt get anywhere because it would compare every single row with all the rows, taking infinity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ca easy do it in 2 Steps:

1) Replace all **http:** to **https:** with **UPDATE IGNORE**

```
UPDATE IGNORE yourTable
set yourField = replace(yourField, 'http:', 'https:')
WHERE yourField LIKE 'http:%';
```

2) SELECT OR DELETE all ROWS start with **http:**

```
SELECT yourTable WHERE yourField LIKE 'http:%';
```

Comment: Does `IGNORE` ignore the unique key?
I can't test it right now since I'm stuck on windows for a while backing up some files...
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Here is a link to the Manual for **IGNORE** from MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/ignore/